# faster take n record in linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq, take

please see this query

```
return ContextDb.TestTbl.AsNoTracking().Where(x =>
                x.Field1 == newsPaperGroupId).OrderByDescending(x => x.ShowDateTime).Take(count).ToList();
```

Is it fetch all record then take n record?

Is there any faster way to do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#deferred-execution), which means that it doesn't retrieve results right away - not until you call certain methods like `ToList()`, `Single()`, `Count()`, or iterate over the query with a `foreach` loop, etc.

If your query looked like this, then it'd actually be grabbing *all* the records where `Field1 == newsPaperGroupId` before taking `count` into consideration.

```
return ContextDb.TestTbl.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.Field1 == newsPaperGroupId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ShowDateTime)
                .ToList()
                .Take(count);
```

And if it looked like this, then it'd be grabbing everything in `TestTbl` *(ouch)* before applying the filter or limiting the number of records taken.

```
return ContextDb.TestTbl.AsNoTracking()
                .ToList()
                .Where(x => x.Field1 == newsPaperGroupId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ShowDateTime)
                .Take(count);
```

But what you've got looks fine. It doesn't retrieve the actual data until you've applied the filter and limited the number of records to retrieve.